# Flask to Django conversion, flask.url_for, flask.request.url

Tags: python, django

I am following the Google OAuth Guide in Django with a Flask example.
But cannot figure some of the code below out. Precisely, how could be flask.url_for, flask.request.url be converted into Django code.

```
# Flask code
flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

# my Django code: just the url???
'http://localhost:8000/api/oauth2callback'

# Flask code
authorization_response = flask.request.url

# my Django code: but it would not work
authorization_response = request.url
```

On  flask.request.url I could not find any docs, any information what it returns

```
state = flask.session['state']
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'],
    state=state)
flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

authorization_response = flask.request.url
flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

# Store the credentials in the session.
# ACTION ITEM for developers:
#     Store user's access and refresh tokens in your data store if
#     incorporating this code into your real app.
credentials = flow.credentials
flask.session['credentials'] = {
    'token': credentials.token,
    'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
    'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
    'client_id': credentials.client_id,
    'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
    'scopes': credentials.scopes}
```

Comment: Are you able to convert flask documentation into django ? I am trying to do so but could not find any resources.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch_token` method extracts parameters in your callback after google redirects users to your app with parameters (code, etc.) and sends a POST request to fetch token and refresh_token.

So, in the Django view of your callback action, you should pass the absolute URL as below:

```
...
authorization_response = request.build_absolute_uri()
flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
...
```